# How do I edit the ico file Visual Studio creates for me?

Tags: visual-studio

In Solution Explorer, Right click -> Add... Icon file.

The file gets created, but looking at it in Visual Studio, it is uneditable.  It includes multiple mips.  If you open in external editor, it opens paint.  If you then make changes and save it, it asks to save it elsewhere and doesn't affect the original ico.

The thing is, I'm sure this has worked for me before.  I'm just not sure what's happening now.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is that Visual Studio does NOT know how to edit PNG targets - even though it adds them to your ico by default.

You'll notice that if you have the image edit bar up, you can in-fact edit the BMP target ones (including pasting over from a more capable image editor ). Further oddness on visual studio's part, you don't appear to be able to add back the PNG targets, so if you delete them they're gone forever unless you have an external ICO editor (which I assume would mean you wouldn't be using the VS one anyway).

Your best bet if you're committed to continuing in VS (several free websites available that will do this for you given some images) is to clear out the unused versions, and add BMP targets for the sizes you care about. The max for BMP is 24 bit, so be aware, but you should be able to keep a fair amount of fidelity, and still keep your transparency (there is a transparent color, and if you paste in with transparency the editor will automatically fill that in for you) - all while keeping the same sizes as the PNG targets.

Hope that helps!
[image: Example icon]

Comment: Thanks for the clear, detailed, and quick response!  It's strange that Visual Studio behaves that way.  This is a good workaround for this issue.